# Esta mal colocar link de un sitio web que creo un post en base a una pregunta

Tags: discusión

Esta mal colocar link de un sitio web que creo un post en base a una pregunta que hizo y se soluciono.

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más específico? ¿Cuál es esa pregunta a la que te refieres?

Comment: No entiendo nada.

Answer (score 2):

No está mal agregar enlaces, porque pueden agregarle importancia a la respuesta. El problema es cuando la respuesta está hecha de puros enlaces y sin ninguna explicación extra, y la falta del código fuente si es necesario.

También hay que tener cuidado con los derechos de autor, en todo caso, incluir el código, y además poner el enlace como fuente.

Si vas abajo de todo en la página, vas a ver lo siguiente:

> Stack Exchange Inc; contribuciones de los usuarios bajo licencia [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) con [atribución requerida](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).